# What's the name of this comic book villain?

Tags: comics, character-identification

As I remember he held a diamond shaped device to his eye & blasted some sort of energy/weapon that expanded from the device.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question would benefit from more detail: when did you see this character? With which other characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be thinking of one of the various incarnations of Eclipso, a DC super villain. Originally Bruce Gordon, a scientist, wounded in an attack by a black diamond. He would transform into Eclipso during an eclipse and use the black diamond to shoot energy bolts from his eyes.
[image]

[image]

[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goJVs.jpg)